# NS record change showing everywhere but locally after 10+ days

Tags: networking, dns

About 12 days ago a friend was messing around with the nameserver record for his domain, trying to change between his old agency to a new Squarespace account. He was able to make the changes to the ns records see it work, revert, and then make the changes one more time all in the same day and saw the changes within a few hours each time.

About 10 days ago I had him set his NameServer record back to the default provided for his domain registrar, GoDaddy, and just point the CNAME and MX records as needed.

So, after all that here's the fun part.  Using https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS I can see that the nameserver changes have taken place everywhere but when I run traceroute I still see the old nameserver. I'm guessing that the local IP is just not releasing the cached record - maybe because he made so many changes to the ns record in one day?

Any idea what's going on or where I should look next?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: As usual, you cannot get any help beyond wild guessing unless you tell us the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a records which contains mentioned server in `/etc/hosts` or `Windows system partition:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and delete them.